# libXmu.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: command-line, package-management, 18.10

i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS
4 GB RAM
intel i3 processor

how can I fix this
error while loading shared libraries: **libXmu.so.6**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe install the missing software? https://pkgs.org/download/libXmu.so.6

Comment: libXmu.so.6 : `sudo apt install libxmu6`

Answer (score 3):

This library [is contained](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libXmu.so.6) in `libxmu6` package.

So you have to install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu6:i386
```